# XAML How to get Canvas's Child to fill the entire Canvas?

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

if I have this XAML:

```
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"> 
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Grid Background="Gray" Margin="5"
        Height="200" Width="200">
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" />
    </Grid>
    <Canvas Background="Gray" Margin="5"
        Height="200" Width="200">
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" />
    </Canvas>
    <StackPanel Background="Gray" Margin="5"
        Height="200" Width="200">
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Only the Grid is filled by the blue rectangle,  But I would like the Canvas to operate the same way and be filled with the blue rectangle?

I am up for making a custom canvas, but not sure how to go about it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
<Canvas x:Name="myCanvas" Background="Gray" Margin="5"
    Height="200" Width="200">
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue"
               Height="{Binding ElementName=myCanvas, Path=ActualHeight}"
               Width="{Binding ElementName=myCanvas, Path=ActualWidth}" />
</Canvas>
```

This will tell the rectangle to take it's dimensions from the actual dimensions of the named element.

The reason only the Grid is filled is because it's the only one that tells it's children what size to be. The StackPanel takes it's size from the combined size of all it's children and the Canvas is the size you tell it to be but doesn't resize any child elements.

Answer (score 4):

Since Canvas doesn't obey [HorizontalAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.horizontalalignment%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and [VerticalAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.verticalalignment%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), you'll have to set the size of the nested element explicitly.

One option is element binding:

```
<Canvas x:Name="theCanvas" Background="Gray" Margin="5" Height="200" Width="200" >
     <Rectangle Fill="Blue" 
                Height="{Binding ElementName=theCanvas, Path=Height}" 
                Width="{Binding ElementName=theCanvas, Path=Width}"  />
</Canvas>
```

which is a bit fragile since it relies on the parent element name (here `myCanvas`).  In WPF, you can get by this with a [RelativeSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) FindAncestor, but not in Silverlight or Windows 8.

You can find a number of workarounds/extensions to fill the FindAncestor gap - [like this one](http://blog.thekieners.com/2010/09/08/relativesource-binding-with-findancestor-mode-in-silverlight/) - so that may be a more reusable option?

You might be able to do something in a converter as well, traversing the visual tree to grab the canvas dimensions.

Comment: Awsome dude, thanks.  I actually discovered this, but had to use ActualHeight, and ActualWidth of the Canvas, it's height and width are often NaN or infinity.